# Android drawer menu with toolbar

Tags: java, android

Is it possible to have a second toolbar which is in the drawer menu that is above my menu list items? I want the toolbar to stick with the sliding menu and overlap the original content and toolbar.
My code:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <!-- our toolbar -->
    <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <!-- frameLayout to display Fragments -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>

<!-- listView to display slider menu -->
<!-- I want to add here a toolbar that will stick to my slide menu-->
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@null"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you want to place a Toolbar in the Sliding Drawer Menu for a nice Header?

One thing you could do, is not necessarily use a Toolbar, but you could create a separate layout file, like this maybe:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:background="@color/blue"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvENumData"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:text="Options"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And then add it as a header to the Sliding Menu by doing this:

```
ViewGroup header = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_title, container, false);
mDrawerListView.addHeaderView(header);
```

This is the Result:

[image]

With this you can have a very nice, easily Customizable Header for your Sliding Menu, if this is not what you want and really want to use the Toolbar then I am sorry for suggesting this, I am just trying to help out.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I wanted to do! Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem at all, happy to help :)